# dom4j.Node iterate maps of elements

Tags: java, dom, dictionary, dom4j

dom4j.Node to process xml files, and I had a problem with Map-similar structures.
I have followed document structure:

```
<Party>
    <Identifier>1113ddbed7b54890abfe2f8c9754d689</Identifier>
    <Address>
    </Address>
<Contact>
    <ContactInfo>
        <Key>IPS</Key>
        <Value>null</Value>
        <Key>keyTwo</Key>
        <Value>1234</Value>
        (...)
    </ContactInfo>
</Contact>
</Party>
```

And my goal is to get value for keyTwo element. How to get those element with flexible, non hardcoded way?

My first idea was something like that:

```
    //parent node is father element
    Node parentDocument = parentNode.selectSingleNode("ContactInfo");
    List<Node> nodesKeys = contactNode.selectNodes("Key");
    List<Node> nodesValues = contactNode.selectNodes("Value");

    for(int i=0; i<nodesKeys.size(); i++){

          if(nodesKeys.get(i).selectSingleNode("Key").equals("keyTwo")){
              return nodesValues.get(i);
          }
    }
```

But I'm not sure if it is good approach, especially if list of keys and values will be correctly ordered.

Comment: What is the size of the xml file ?

Comment: Not big, something like 1-2 hundred lines

Comment: if you have a bigfile > some Megabytes, you can combine Xpath + Dom4j and stream nodes, every parsed node should be detached from dom tree after processing to free the ram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete working example:

Maven : PoM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sofrecom</groupId>
    <artifactId>XmlProcessing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Java Main:

```
package xmlprocessing;

import org.dom4j.Document;
import org.dom4j.DocumentException;
import org.dom4j.Node;
import org.dom4j.io.SAXReader;

/**
 *
 * @author z.benrhouma
 */
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        try {
            Document document =  parse("src/main/resources/file.xml");
            Node node = document.selectSingleNode( "//Party/Contact/ContactInfo/Key[text()='keyTwo']/following-sibling::Value[1]");
            System.out.println(node.getText());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
    public static Document parse(String path) throws DocumentException {
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Document document = reader.read(path);
        return document;
    }
}
```

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Party>
    <Identifier>1113ddbed7b54890abfe2f8c9754d689</Identifier>
    <Address>
    </Address>
    <Contact>
        <ContactInfo>
            <Key>IPS</Key>
            <Value>null</Value>
            <Key>keyTwo</Key>
            <Value>1234</Value>

        </ContactInfo>
    </Contact>
</Party>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think dom4j+[Xpath](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html) will resolve the problem , you just need to add [jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/) dependency.

```
// ContactInfo Element having key = 'keyTwo'
Node node = document.selectSingleNode( "//Party/Contact/ContactInfo[Key = 'keyTwo']");
// retrieve data from the selected node
String value = node... ;
```

Maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Cheers.

Comment: What Node will be returned from .selectSingleNode( "//Party/Contact/ContactInfo/[Key = 'keyTwo']"); ? If it will be only <Key>keyTwo</Key> ? or pair <Key>keyTwo</Key><Value>1234</Value> ?

Comment: //Party/Contact/ContactInfo/ ==> ContactInfo

Comment: Can You help me with this query? I will be appreciate